# Power Query List.Generate iteration bug

Tags: powerquery

I am using the following List.Generate function in a Power Query workflow, but not getting the desired results:

```
outcome_list = List.Generate (
    () => [page = 1, result = fnGetFindings(1,outcome_id)],
    each not List.IsEmpty([result]),
    each [page= [page] + 1, result = fnGetFindings([page],outcome_id)],
    each [result]
)
```

The function fnGetFindings uses two parameters. The first being the page number. When I invoke page 2 manually it returns empty, but my result is duplicating page 1 which is the first iteration by default. I am therefore getting two lists of results back from page 1, but it should only be one list.

How can I fix this M code to only return page 1 once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use

```
() => [page = 2, result = fnGetFindings(1,outcome_id)],
```